# How to get target button clicked on form submmit

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I need to know have a way to get the target button I clicked in form. My table is like this:

[image]

```js
$('#frmUpload').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(e.target.nodeName);
  return false;
});
```

The upload button submits the form, and activates that event. However  `e.target.nodeName` shows `FORM`, not the button I click.

I need to know which button I clicked because I need to know what image I will upload or delete and send `formData` to an AJAX call.

**Edit**: i solve this problem using that:

```js
    $('#frmUpload').on('submit', function(e){
        var $btn = $(document.activeElement);
        alert($btn);

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: You don't need to get the button at all. You can traverse the DOM to find the file `input` within the `form` which was submit, eg. `$(this).find('.my-file-input')`. I'd be interested to see your HTML, though, as to have multiple submit buttons you'll need a `form` per row, but that in turn would invalidate your `table` HTML structure...

Comment: you can use $('#btn').on('click', function(e){ // you handle here});

Comment: since you have multiple instance of button, you cannot do that with Id, Do it with a class name. You would get a class name by $(".my-class-name")